# Asymmetrical power input into an RF Combiner?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I have two 23CM RF Amplifiers - One outputs 150W and the second 250W. Both accept the same RF input and I wanted to know if an RF combiner can accept asymmetrical inputs to provide a combined 400W out.

Comment: How are you going to ensure that the outputs of the two amplifiers are in  phase?

Comment: It sounds like they are totally different amplifiers, and thus as @SteveSh says the outputs are not likely to be in phase unless you've taken specific steps to make sure. Even if they are in phase, it depends on the RF combiner topology. Simple topologies depend on the two sources being equal, if they aren't power can backflow into the weaker source.

Comment: And I'm not an expert on RF combiners, but I do know that Wilkinson combiners will do what you want.